# WP_MAIL() not sending attachments

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I am working on one plugin in which I need to send email with attachment(s). I have tried with below code but its not working for me. Its sending email but without attachment. Please guide me if I am doing anything wrong.

attachment array is as below :

> [attachments] => Array (
>       [0] => https://www.xxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/test.docx )

NOTE : I have checked that attachment file has 644 file permission.

> $attachments = array(); if(isset($email['attachments']) &&
>   count($email['attachments'])>0){
>       $attachments = $email['attachments']; }
>
> $headers = array();
>
> $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
>
> $headers[] = 'From: ' . $from_name . ' <' . $from_address . '>';
>
> if(isset($email['reply_name']) && isset($email['reply_to'])){
>
> ```
> $headers[] = 'Reply-To: ' . $email['reply_name'] . ' <' . $email['reply_to'] . '>';
> ```
>
> }elseif(isset($email['reply_to'])){
>
> ```
> $headers[] = 'Reply-To: <' . $email['reply_to'] . '>';
> ```
>
> }
>
> wp_mail($email['recipients'], $email['subject'], $email['content'],
>   $headers, $attachments);

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you give your result for "**$attachments**" ?

Thx.

**[EDIT]**

You need a special format to send an attachment :

```
    $attachments = array( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/file_to_attach.zip' );
```

Comment: I have updated question. you can find it there please.

Comment: [attachments] => Array ( [0] => https://www.xxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/test.docx )

Comment: Ok, thx. Now I understand why it does not work.

You need a special format to send an attachment : 

**$attachments = array( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/file_to_attach.zip' );**

Try to have this URL format and it will work.

Comment: Wow... Its working now. Thank you very much for this help.